# Strong customer authentication in stripe

Tags: ajax, stripe-payments

I have implemented Strong customer authentication in stripe. 
its working on test mode, but not working on live mode I want to know the payment method for live mode?

```
function createPaymentIntent(plan_id,customer_id) {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents',
                headers: {
                   Authorization: 'Bearer sk_live_*******************'
                },
                data: {
                    customer: customer_id,
                    amount: Math.round(amount*100),
                    confirmation_method: 'automatic',
                    payment_method: 'pm_card_threeDSecure2Required',
                    confirm: true,
                    currency: currency,
                },
                success: (response) => {
                  console.log("payment" + response['client_secret']);
                  var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_********************');
                  var elements = stripe.elements();
                  try {
                      stripe.handleCardPayment(
                        response['client_secret']
                      ).then(function(result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                            $('#hvalidation').hide();
                             $('.checkout-title').after('<span id="errmsg">Please complete the authentication process</span>');
                          // Display error.message in your UI.
                        } else {
                            createSubscription(plan_id,customer_id);
                          // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
                        }
                      });
                   }
                catch(error) {
                  console.log(error.message);
                }
                },
                error: (response) => {
                  console.log(response);
                }
              })
             }
```

Actual Result- Authentication model is not displaying on live mode.
Expected Result- Authentication model should display on live mode.

Comment: The reason why it is so is because you are using a Stripe testing payment method `pm_card_threeDSecure2Required ` in the payment_intent creation. 

Another thing is that you should NEVER call stripe API directly in your front end using stripe secret key. Your stripe secret key can be easily compromised. The secret key is essentially your bank account password which you do not want to put in your web application frontend.

Comment: I want to know the replacement for "pm_card_threeDSecure2Required" method for live mode

Comment: @Rupali, in livemode that will be the token for the real live payment method. Meaning, this would be something like pm_card_xxx123 or whatever is returned when creating the payment method.

Comment: Yes It's working after creating through payment method API